# can't access vm on Google Cloud, block by Windows firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 2008 server on Google cloud and setting "block all programs" on Windows firewall accidentally.

So I couldn't access this server with RDP/ftp/web/SQL now.

Does anyone know how to turn off Windows firewall in this situation??

Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try connecting to the serial [console port 2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole). Once there:

- Type "cmd", you should get an output like the one below

SAC>cmd The Command Prompt session was successfully launched.
SAC> EVENT: A new channel has been created. Use "ch -?" for channel help.
Channel: Cmd0001

- Type below command to get command prompt inside windows

SAC>ch -sn Cmd0001

If you cannot recover the instance to its previous state, the next steps you can perform to recover the server's data are:

- Promote the [external IP to static](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) if not yet done.
- Edit the instance and uncheck the box next to "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted". Save the changes and delete the instance. You will keep the disk.
- Create a new instance, it will be your new server. For this purpose you can assign the same static IP (if you promoted it as static) used in the original instance. Edit the instance and add the disk as an additional disk. Save the changes.
- RDP to the new instances and run the disk manager ("diskmgmt.msc"). You will see the additional disk you attached showing a message like "the disk is offline because it has a signature collision with another disk that is online", you just need to right click on it and set it as "Online".
- Once done you will be able to retrieved any data you need from the original instance.